# Copy Excel tables to Outlook email with Python

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, pywin32

I'm using pywin32 with python3 and I'm trying to copy some pivot tables into a formatted email in Outlook. I have the Excel side done, but not sure on the Outlook side. I can paste tables into the email, but I'd like to have formatted text before and after them. I was thinking of possibly storing a template-type thing in a Word document, but not sure what to do

I have something like

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xlsx = xl.Workbooks.Open('doc.xlsx')
xlsx.Sheets.Item('Some Sheet').PivotTables('PivotTable 1').TableRange2.Copy()

word = Dispatch('Word.Application')
docx = word.Documents.Open('doc.docx')
docx.Bookmarks('PivotTable1').Range.PasteExcelTable(False, False, False)
docx.Content.Copy()

outlook = Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.BodyFormat = 3
we = mail.GetInspector.WordEditor
we.Range().Paste()
```

Edit: Figured out a way to get it to work using an intermediary Word document as a template with Bookmarks as locations to insert things. Open to suggestions of better ways to do this, though.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate on what you are doing with a Word document? You put tables in the Word document, then copy the contents into Outlook message body?

Comment: The Word document is a template with other items inside and bookmarks as place holders. Certain tables get copied in then the entire contents with headers and descriptions gets inserted into an email